# Are there any Tridentine Rite Catholic communities that also use the Liturgical Calendar of 1970?

Tags: catholicism, religious-practice, liturgy, liturgical-calendar

The Roman Catholic Church has two Liturgical Forms of Mass in usage at the moment: The Ordinary Form of the Mass (of Pope Paul VI) and the Extraordinary Form of the Mass (of Pope Pius V).

Usually those who use the Tridentine Mass (1962) follow the [Liturgical Calendar of 1960.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_Roman_Calendar_of_1960)

My question is simple: Are there any Tridentine Rite Catholics that in the usage of this Rite have also freely and legitimately employe the [Liturgical Calendar of 1970](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mysterii_Paschalis) in lieu of the older calendar?

Answer (score 1):

To the best of my knowledge, the decree "Summorum Pontificum" designating the (more-or-less) traditional rite as the "extraordiary form" of the Roman rite says that it must be celebrated according to the liturgy and calendar of 1962.

Answer (score 0):

The Ordinariate Use contained in *Divine Worship:The Missal* is very close in form to the Extraordinary Form. But it's in Tudor English, not Latin.

It's based on the Novus Ordo but contains an enormous amount of material which dates from before 1970, including some pre-Reformation Sarum Use. It's **primarily designed** to be celebrated *ad orientem,* and all the propers were originally published before 1960. The Mass can even include the Last Gospel and the Leonine Prayers (including the Prayer to St Michael).

However, the Lectionary and Calendar is that of 1970, and subject to the rulings of Bishops' Councils which (for example) place the Feast of the Ascension on a Sunday.